# How to get the value of Queryset in Django

Tags: python, django

How to get this value `covid_id` and convert it to list? in QuerySet?

```
<QuerySet [{'covid_id': 1653718671360'},{'covid_id': '1624728932475'}]>
```

*Expected output*

```
['1653718671360','1624728932475']
```

*sample*

```
sample= Person.objects.filter(pk__in=product_ids).values('covid_id') #output<QuerySet [{'covid_id': 1653718671360'},{'covid_id': '1624728932475'}]>
print(sample)
```

Comment: `list(Person.objects.filter(pk__in=product_ids).values_list('covid_id', flat=True))`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
sample = list(Person.objects.filter(pk__in=product_ids).values_list('covid_id', flat=True))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Answer (score 0):

just iterate over the `queryset`:

```
your_qs = <QuerySet [{'covid_id': 1653718671360'},{'covid_id': '1624728932475'}]>

for q in your_qs:
    print(q['covid_id'])
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.